# HTML embed uses wrong relative path

Tags: html

#### Problem

I have three files in two locations: `html2` in a parent folder, `html1` and `img.png` in a subfolder. I embed `folder/html1` in `html2` using html `<embed>`-tags. `folder/html1` contains `img.png` as a relative path. When I open `html1` as a stand-alone file, the image is displayed correctly. However, the image is not shown in the embedded version because the path is now interpreted relative to `html2` (the image is expected in the parent folder).

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!––html2-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <embed src="folder/html1.html">
      <head>
        <!––html1-->
      </head>
      <body>
        <img src="img.png"></img>
      </body>
    </embed>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### Question

How to make my browser show the image without moving files or rewriting the html code? Is there any way to make html automatically "rewrite" relative paths when using `embed`?

#### Considered solutions

I considered moving all files to the same folder but I find that rather unelegant. Using absolute paths is difficult because `html1` is generated automatically. There must be a better solution?

Comment: The [`<base>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) might help you

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Given different `img.png` files in both `./` and `./folder`, when I load `html1.html` in my browser, each file with an `<img>` shows a different image.

Comment: Note, however, that the element **designed** for including one HTML document in another is `<iframe>`

Answer (score 0):

The point goes to Quentin. I tried the minimum example again and it works. The relative paths are resolved correctly by default. The reason why it did not work in my (unreferenced) original code was because both html files are created by a python code that copies both to a new location but not the image. Thus there was no image in the new location and nothing to display. My bad!

@Quentin: Thanks for your comment. Made me check again. How can I give you credit?

@Carl: Thanks for the hint! I didn't know about the base tag. Did not need it after all but maybe in the future!